# When I do SCP of big files my Mac becomes very sluggish

Tags: performance, scp

Whenever I try to use SCP to upload files to my server, performance goes down. It slows down so much that I cannot even see the mouse pointer.

I have a MacBook AIR i5, with 4GB of RAM.

I don't see a problem in Activity Monitor.  The CPU stays at 20% load.

[image: Activity Monitor]

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: When you upload a big file, your computer has to read it on your disk. Watch for "Disk Activity" instead of "CPU" and "System Memory", depend on your network speed but it must be your HDD which slow down your computer.

Comment: @epingle but it is SSD, it should be fast reading. I never had problems with scp on conventional rotating disk hdds.

Comment: My bad I didn't know :-) I have no other idea :/

Comment: so no clues? no one?